# Why is the Xcode Analyzer given me a memory leak warning with this code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

Warning is:

> Potential leak of an object stored into 'escaped_value'

Here is the code:

```
- (NSURL*)generateURL:(NSString*)baseURL params:(NSDictionary*)params {
    if (params) {
        NSMutableArray* pairs = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (NSString* key in params.keyEnumerator) {
            NSString* value = params[key];
            NSString* escaped_value = (__bridge NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                                                                                          NULL, /* allocator */
                                                                                          (__bridge CFStringRef)value,
                                                                                          NULL, /* charactersToLeaveUnescaped */
                                                                                          (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                                                                          kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

            [pairs addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", key, escaped_value]];
        }

        NSString* query = [pairs componentsJoinedByString:@"&"];
        NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?%@", baseURL, query];
        return [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    } else {
        return [NSURL URLWithString:baseURL];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating a string when you call CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes and never CFReleasing it. Either CFRelease the object before it goes out of scope or change the __bridge to __bridge_transfer to let ARC take care of it.

__bridge_transfer tells ARC that during the cast that a +1 retain count on the object is being transferred to be under ARCs responsibility. ARC will release the instance according to its rules.

__bridge tells ARC that retain counts are not being transferred during the cast.

Comment: Is there a reason I shouldn't be using __bridge_transfer?

Comment: I would use __bridge_transfer instead of manually having to deal with the retain.

Comment: @EthanAllen: You can also use the CFBridgingRelease() macro which uses __bridge_transfer, but make the "release" more obvious.